# Are there any Azure resources on the conversion of a CentOS node.js to an Azure PaaS node.js app?

Tags: node.js, azure, centos

Are there any Azure resources (documentation or otherwise) that explain the conversion of a CentOS node.js app to an Azure Platform-as-a-Service node.js app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, I think it's not a difficult thing. Azure support a lot of Services & Components to help migrating different layouts of your nodejs app into suitable services on Azure.

If your nodejs app is a web app, you can refer to these documents below:

1. Build and deploy nodejs web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/
2. Use WebMatrix to build and deploy nodejs web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-use-webmatrix/
3. Deploy web app thru different ways: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/

If your nodejs app used MySQL, you can purchase ClearDB (or install MySQL on Azure VM) or create a Web Site with 20M free MySQL database. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/.

If you used MSSQL as nodejs app database, you just migrate all data into Azure SQL Database by following https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-nodejs-simple-windows/.

If you used MongoDB, you can replace it with Azure DocumentDB https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-nodejs-application/ or access MongoDB installed on Azure VM https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-store-data-mongodb-vm/.

And there is a third party MongoDB service on Azure https://mongolab.com/azure/.

I think the simple way for your issue is use Azure IaaS to create a CentOS VM to migrate your nodejs app. When you used some special feature on local CentOS, this way is a correct choice.Please refer to the section "CentOS" of the page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-opensource/.

Best Regards.